# NDK compile warnings on OCR tesseract libraries for android

Tags: android, android-ndk, ocr, tess-two

I am trying to compile android NDK version of OCR tesseract libraries tess-two but I am confused why I am getting the following warning. I have just downloaded the library from the github and trying to compile using NDK r9b.

> C:\NV_ANDROIDPACK_BACKUP\android-ndk-r9b\tess-two>C:\NV_ANDROIDPACK_BACKUP\andr
>   id-ndk-r9b\ndk-build
>   Android NDK: WARNING:jni/com_googlecode_tesseract_android/Android.mk:tess: non-
>   ystem libraries in linker flags: -latomic
>   Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_
>   TATIC_LIBRARIES
>   Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependen
>   ies of the
>   Android NDK:     current module
>   [armeabi] Compile thumb  : jpgt <= jaricom.c

Also on each file at the time of compilation it shows following warning as well

```
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: tess <= params_model.cpp
clang++.exe: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fpermissive'
warning: unknown warning option '-Wno-shift-negative-value'; did you mean
      '-Wno-shift-sign-overflow'? [-Wunknown-warning-option]
```

kindly help how to solve this.

Comment: Why not [use](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two#usage) the precompiled version of the project?

Comment: i couldn't find precompiled version , can you show me the link ?

Comment: The link in my comment above (see "Usage" in the Readme) makes reference to a line you can add to your app's build.gradle file that will add tess-two to your project as a precompiled external dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of the NDK that you're using is too old. If you update your NDK to r12b, you'll avoid seeing that error.