# Android NDK: iostream file not found

Tags: android, android-ndk, tesseract, tess-two

I have tried quite a lot of suggestions regarding this problem, but none seem to solve my problem.

This is what I am giving as a command:

```
 C:\Users\{name}\Desktop\MyApplication\libraries\tess-two-master\tess-two\jni> C:\Users\{name}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\android-ndk-r19\ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=. APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=./Android.mk
```

I am not able to compile com_googlecode_tesseract_android/./src/api/baseapi.cpp
It gives me this error:

```
Android NDK: WARNING:com_googlecode_tesseract_android/Android.mk:tess: non-system libraries in linker flags: -latomic
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the
Android NDK:     current module

com_googlecode_tesseract_android/./src/api/baseapi.cpp:45:10: fatal error
    'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
     ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/tess/./src/api/baseapi.o] Error 1
```

Here is my Application.mk

```
    APP_STL:= c++_shared
    APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a x86 arm64-v8a x86_64
    APP_OPTIM := release
    APP_PLATFORM := android-16
    APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions -frtti
    NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang
```

Here is my Android.mk

```
     LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
     TESSERACT_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/com_googlecode_tesseract_android/src
     LEPTONICA_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/src
     LIBJPEG_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/libjpeg
     LIBPNG_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/libpng

     # Just build the Android.mk files in the subdirs
     include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
```

The same error shows up for all 4 headers in baseapi.cpp -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
```

If anyone can help me figure out what is the problem here, it'll be great. Thank you.

PS: I am using NDK r19

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NDK compile warnings on OCR tesseract libraries for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38675799/ndk-compile-warnings-on-ocr-tesseract-libraries-for-android)

Comment: There's no `arch-arm64` directory in `platforms/android-16`. At least not in the NDK I have installed. It only exists for `android-21` and later platforms.

Comment: @Michael I have not changed anything besides APP_STL. I directly downloaded it from the website.

Comment: @Michael ndk-build knows that and will pull-up to 21 for 64-bit ABIs.

Comment: You can simply include `#ifdef __cplusplus
#endif ` in all of your header files in which you're facing this issue.  `__cplusplus` will be defined for any compilation unit that is being run through the C++ compiler. It works really well. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation, your `ndk-build` does not load the **Application.mk** file automatically. You must specify it explicitly:

```
…ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=. APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=./Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=./Application.mk
```

Or you can run `ndk-build` from the **tess-two** directory (the one above **jni**). In this case, `ndk-build` will find both **.mk** files, and you don't need to specify `NDK_PROJECT_PATH`:

```
…ndk-build
```

The only difference is that the output (**obj** and **libs** directories) will be created near, not in the **jni** directory.